# Is it possible to maintain a track record of each CSV column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using Pandas to load a CSV and then perform some operations, data manipulations, etc. It all starts very simple:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=7)
```

After all the manipulations, the data will be exported to a CSV, JSON or something like that for importing into a database. It would be useful to have a record of the original CSV row number and row contents so we can backtrack any issues found later on. Is that possible? How should it be done?

So, for example, I start with:

```
name, height
Arnold Schwarzenegger, 188
Danny De Vito, 147
```

I process the data into:

```
[{"first_name": "Arnold", "last_name": "Schwarzenegger", "height": 1.88},
 {"first_name": "Danny De", "last_name": "Vito", "height": 1.47}]
```

and I import into the database (PostgreSQL running in production). Later on we discover that Danny DeVito's name was mangled, was it the processing or the original data? So, I want to export the data into:

```
[{"first_name": "Arnold", "last_name": "Schwarzenegger", "height": 1.88,
  "csv_line_number": 1, "csv_line": "Arnold Schwarzenegger, 188"},
 {"first_name": "Danny De", "last_name": "Vito", "height": 1.47,
  "csv_line_number": 2, "csv_line": "Danny De Vito, 147"}]
```

So that just by inspecting the database we can start to develop some understanding of what happened.

Comment: Can't you just make a copy of the original and then you can just compare e.g. `df_orig == df` will return a boolean mask where the values are the same

Comment: @EdChum: I'm not sure what you mean by a copy of the original. The result of the pandas manipulation will be exported and imported into a database. I need that to have a track record of the original CSV row.

Comment: `df_orig = df.copy()` for a clone of the original dataframe

Comment: If you want the original row, you can call `df = df.reset_index()` which will add the index as a column, you can rename the column if necessary and the row number will persist with the df

Comment: I need the original row in an export. By the time I want to look at the original row, the dataframe no longer exists, it's been exported to a CSV or JSON.

Comment: i also find it useful to print out `df.shape` after every manipulation that changes the dataframe size such as subsetting

Comment: for a similar purpose, I use `pydqc` package. It automatically generates data summary report for each column and summarizes statistical differences between columns of two dataframes.

Comment: But I don't have two dataframes, I have one.

Answer (score 0):

By far the safest and simplest way to "backtrack things later" is to simply repeat:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

...and then use that to do whatever verification you want to do.

In the scenario where you want to copy the dataframe, then it's better to use:

```
df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
```

...this way you make sure you get an actual full copy. This copy would also avoid destruction resulting from making changes to a dataframe inside a helper function or other similar situation.

If your dataset is very large and taking copies is not a good idea, and for some reason simply repeating the reading of the original csv (which will be safest), more information is needed regarding the kind of verification you want to do. For example, just storing storing what you get from `df.describe()` would give you a relatively good basis for verification later. But again, this would depend on how critical the system in question is, among other things.

If the case is to just resolve "how to put the original line number and entire row of a CSV file that's been opened with pd.read_csv() as new columns in the dataframe", you do it by:

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv')
df['original'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1)
df['row_id'] = range(len(df))
```

Your dataframe now has two new columns:

- column with row_id starting from 0
- column with comma separated original records (rows)

Note that I would not use `df.reset_index()` as a way to generate a row number index as it is a bad practice that will lead to issues in other cases.

Comment: I cannot copy a dataframe. By the time I'm using the information, it's been exported back to csv or json and the dataframe doesn't exist anymore. Also, I'm looking for a solution to the CSV not existing or being accessible anymore. If someone is looking at the database and sees some data that looks wrong, they should be able to look at the original record from the CSV to try to figure out whether there was a problem in the data handling or the original data was already problematic.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Can you explain more about the degree of validation you are looking for, and I will complement the answer accordingly. Do you need to be able to exactly verify each cell (intersection of row and column), each record (a row), each feature (a column)...and if yes, which one. Or is it enough to have something more "heuristic".

Comment: I just need to have a value/cell containing the whole of the original row (and row number ideally). I elaborated on this on the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, did I misunderstand something, or is there a contradiction in the position you are assuming i.e. you can't have access to the CSV anymore, but you are ready to store something. Or is it that you can't have access to the CSV anymore, and you can't store anything locally (?!), and you would like to keep a reference in memory?

Comment: The data is stored in a database. The CSV may or may not be gone or inaccessible.The information should be in the database.

Comment: If the CSV is gone and you can't store a sufficient copy locally, and you can't keep anything in memory, as you point out, the information has to be stored in a database. But because you are trying to solve the problem of verifying records in a database with the original, you now have a problem of verifying the records in the database which is for the  purpose of verifying records in another database...ad infinitum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189216/discussion-between-mikkokotila-and-pupeno).